# Best practice architecture of React Native with using Websocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, websocket

I am building crypto exchange app with using React-Native and WebSocket. Here is my general issues:

1. Once I assign webSocket out of the class it does not connect event. How can I create singleton WebSocket instance? Here is my code:

```
class WS {
  webSocket: WebSocket;

  constructor() {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket('socket_url');
    this.webSocket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
  }

  _send(coin: string, type: Subject) {
    const subPackage = new SubscribePackage(`${coin}@${type}`);
    this.webSocket.onopen = () => {
      const message = onSendMessageObjNew(subPackage);
      this.webSocket.send(message);
    };
  }

  _message(callback: (event: MessageEvent<any>) => void) {
    this.webSocket.onmessage = callback;
  }

  _unsubscribe(coin: string, type: Subject) {
    const unsubPackage = new UnsubscribePackage(`${coin}@${type}`);
    const message = onSendMessageObjNew(unsubPackage);
    this.webSocket.send(message);
  }

  _error(callback: (event: Event) => void) {
    this.webSocket.onerror = callback;
  }
}
```

2. I am connecting every piece of coin inside component that is easier to manage whole process. I assume that it is the best way to centralize and cache whole connection inside redux with using rtq stream update but this way I will have huge amount of performance problem. Which way do you think is better?
3. I want to unsubscribe some event when screen is not focus (while navigate other screen). If user back same screen it will reconnected again. It is not subscribed event after unsubscribe same event. Here is the my code snippet:

```
const ws = useMemo(() => new WS(), []);
  const onSubscribe = () => {
    if(__DEV__) console.log('onSubscribe called!');

    ws._send(name, Subject.Field);
    ws._message(async event => {
      // data manipulation
    });
    ws._error(event => {
      if (__DEV__) console.log('error event>>>', event);
    });
  };

  const onUnSubscribe = () => {
    ws._unsubscribe(name, Subject.Field);
  };

  const screenListenerHandler = () => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', onSubscribe);
    navigation.addListener('blur', onUnSubscribe);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    screenListenerHandler();
  }, []);
```

4. I want to run WebSocket operations in the background thread for not blocking UI and JS threads. How can I do that or even possible?
5. If you have other suggestions that I haven't mentioned, please share your practice.

Comment: This might be helpful, [Architecture in a react native app using WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994344/architecture-in-a-react-native-app-using-websockets)